# How to delete similar value from a list and print the remaining

Tags: python, list

```
list =[('1', '5'), ('3', '5'), ('4', '5'), ('5', '1'), ('5', '3'), ('5', '4')]
```

above is a generated list now i want to write only (5,1) for (1,5) and (5,1) too same with the other values.

Desired output

```
list = [('5', '1'), ('5', '3'), ('5', '4')]
```

Comment: If this is homework, please edit to add the homework tag.

Comment: [list](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#list) is a function, so it's best to avoid using it as a variable name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the item to the new list if its reverse is not also in the list, or the item is larger than its reverse.

```
newlist = []
for item in oldlist:
    rev = item[::-1]
    if (not (rev in oldlist)) or (item > rev)
        newlist.append(item)
```

Comment: it does not maintain the order that is specified in the desired ouput :(

Comment: for large lists you better use a `set` it's lot more effective for searching.

Comment: @yi_H True, but performance wasn't part of the question. @mama just do `oldset = set(oldlist)` before the loop and `(rev in oldset)` instead of `(rev in oldlist)` if you need to speed it up for long lists.

Comment: @GreenMatt I didn't use `list` as a variable name, you should post that as a comment on the question if you'd like.

Comment: @agf:  Oops!  That's what I meant to do (and have done now).  Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

```
l = [('1', '5'), ('3', '5'), ('4', '5'), ('5', '1'), ('5', '3'), ('5', '4')]

s=set()
for e in l:
  if e[0] >= e[1]:
    s.add(e)
  else:
    s.add((e[1], e[0]))

l = list(s)
```

Note: it doesn't preserve the order. If that is important:

```
s=set(); l2 = []
for e in l:
  if e[0] < e[1]:
    e = (e[1], e[0])
  if not e in s:
    s.add(e)
    l2.append(e)
```

Comment: Doesn't maintain order, which may be important (it probably isn't, but the question didn't specify).

Answer (score 0):

```
li =[('1', '5'), ('3', '5'), ('4', '5'), ('5', '1'), ('5', '3'), ('5', '4')]

gen = ((a,b) if a>b else (b,a) for a,b in li)
lu = []
[lu.append(y) for y in gen if y not in lu]

print lu
```

Answer (score 0):

If order isn't important, you can achieve this with the [list](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#list) and [set](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#set) functions in a one liner like the following:

```
orig_list =[('1', '5'), ('3', '5'), ('4', '5'), ('5', '1'), ('5', '3'), ('5', '4')]
modified_list = list(set([(t[0], t[1]) if t[0] > t[1] else (t[1], t[0]) for t in orig_list]))
```

Concise, if a bit dense.

Answer (score 0):

```
my_list = [('1', '5'), ('3', '5'), ('4', '5'), ('5', '1'), ('5', '3'), ('5', '4')]
new_list = [(a, b) if (a > b) else (b, a) for a, b in my_list]
result = list(set(new_list))
```